# How do I swap strings using PHP preg_replace?

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, preg-replace-callback

I have CSS code and I want to swap **left with right** and **right with left**.

Here is example CSS:

```
.test{text-align:left;margin-left:10px;float:right}
.test_right{text-align:left;border-right:0px;border-left:1px}
.test_left{float:right}
```

Should be:

```
.test{text-align:right;margin-right:10px;float:left}
.test_right{text-align:right;border-left:0px;border-right:1px}
.test_left{float:left}
```

I have the following preg_replace, but it only matches 1 instance in each {} and I need it to match all instances.

```
$css = preg_replace('/({.*?)left(.*?})/i', '$1right$2', $css);
```

The other problem with this is that I can't swap **left and right** because everything would be **right** after I run the first preg_replace.  How could I solve that issue?  Perhaps using preg_replace_callback?

Comment: `strtr($css, array('left' => 'right', 'right' => 'left'))`

Comment: This does NOT solve my problem and the questions are different. I'm so sick of people closing questions on this site when they shouldn't be.

Comment: Apologies - I read your text which said "swap left with right and right with left", which is what that code does, but I did not look at your example data carefully enough to see that you are not swapping all the words. Again, sorry, and I have reopened the question.

Comment: You need a combination of `preg_replace_callback` and `strtr`: https://3v4l.org/PSsT7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to successfully figure it out.

```
function callback($match)
{
    $matchit = strtr($match[0], array('left' => 'right', 'right' => 'left'));
    return $matchit;
}

$css= preg_replace_callback('/{(.*?)}/i', 'callback', $css);
echo $css;
```

The preg_replace_callback is returning anything between { and }.  The callback function is replacing left and right.

I am further refining this function to add some kind of ignore trigger so the PHP will ignore certain classes/IDs.  Also, it will need to do some reversing on padding and margin, among other things.  The entire thing will be made into a class for anyone using PHP to convert CSS to RTL easily.

**Update:**

You can use this preg_replace instead:

```
$css = preg_replace_callback('/{(?!\/\*i\*\/)(.*?)}/i', 'callback', $css);
```

Then you can put /*i*/ into any line you want it to ignore.  For example:

```
.test{/*i*/margin-left:0px;text-align:right}
```